# Facebooks "include original post" missing for shared FB videos?

Tags: facebook

I want to share a friend's post (she shared a video of certain page) also with her comment. I know facebook had this checkbox "include original post", but it is just not there! How to proceed? I really want to share her comment as well. Did facebook remove that option? Thanks!

Comment: Aahhhh.. now I see... lots of people complaining about this... it's madness: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10161813636565078

Answer (score 0):

When I pressed "share" on desktop, I chose "write post", and there was no option I could see to include original post, just an emoji. However, when I did the same via mobile (Android), I could press the three dotted lines, and it brought up a context menu with "include original post" or "link only".